# Set the Progress Bar Value according to data entered?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How can Set the Progress Bar Value increasing/ decreasing according to data entered in each controls on a form ? I mean, I am working with number of controls, so go for a sample [Suppose I have **four textboxes**, Progress Bar Maximum 100, when entering txt_1 Progress value have to increase to 100/4= 25, if I remove data from txt_1 the Value should decreased to Zero.

Sorry for my language, I am not good in English.

Can any one help me, please..... Thank You.

Comment: A = number of control. B = number of controls have value. And then calculate B/A. You have to calculate B/A again when the user enters any controls.

Comment: Can you explain me .. please ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firs thing you do is set the progressbar maximum in your formload event to the number of textboxes you are using.

```
Dim TextBoxNumber As Integer = 4
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = TextBoxNumber
End Sub
```

Then you need to make 2 events.
1. TextBox enter event."Private Sub TextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)"
2. TextBox TextChanged event"Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)"

Then Link all the textboxes you want to use to the events.
[image]
[image]

In these events you will use the Sender.
Make a Dim and convert the sender to type Textbox to use its properties." Dim TextControl As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)"

In the Enter event you count the text that is entered in the textbox.
If the count is 0 you set the boolean to true and if its more than 0 you set the Boolean to False.
This Boolean you will use in the Text Change event.

```
Dim CheckTextBox As Boolean
Private Sub TextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.Enter, TextBox3.Enter, TextBox2.Enter, TextBox1.Enter
    Dim TextControl As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If TextControl.Text.Count > 0 Then
        CheckTextBox = False
    Else
        CheckTextBox = True
    End If
End Sub
```

In the Text Change event you need to do a few things.
1.Use a if statement to check if the textbox is empty."This will only trigger if the user deletes the text in the textbox."
  So if empty remove 1 from the progressbar and set CheckTextBox"Boolean" to True 
  "ProgressValue = ProgressValue - 1"
  "CheckTextBox = True"

2.Then use a ElseIf to check if the CheckTextBox"Boolean" is True.
If true add 1 to progressbar and set Boolean to false.
"ProgressValue = ProgressValue + 1"
"CheckTextBox = False"

You need to set the Boolean to false because otherwise you will add 25 for every time you add somthing to the textbox.

```
Dim ProgressValue As Integer
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged, TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim TextControl As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)

    If TextControl.Text = "" Then
        ProgressValue = ProgressValue - 1
        CheckTextBox = True

    ElseIf CheckTextBox = True Then
        ProgressValue = ProgressValue + 1
        CheckTextBox = False
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressValue
End Sub
```

Comment: it is not working for my combobox, can u help one more. ? I am using Dotnetbar ComboBoxEx

Comment: @Koyas i dont know dotnetbar. but dos the combobox have SelectedIndexChanged event ? if yes use it.

Comment: i am fully considering all ur help, also its a greate thing, Sorry, Actually i am new to VB. When i using SelectedIndexChanged event all of its functions are right but when the combobox text wend blank the progressValue not minusing, I have tried the code in combobox TextChanged event. while-- entering in combobox1 progressValue increasing correctly, then i selected Combo2 with no text and then reselect Combo1 the progressVal wend zero, also Combo1 remaining the text on it.

Comment: DotNetBar I mentioned before is some components with additional features than Windows Default components, u can found in THIS [link](http://www.devcomponents.com/). If u need using it u can download its Ver.11.9 from THIS [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bbqybiz0igoxn6p/DevComponents%20DotNetBar%20for%20Windows%20Forms%2011.9.0.1.rar?dl=0). Latest is Ver.12

Comment: @Koyas was verry buzy yes.I wil try it today.or make a new question about dotnetbar combobox.mybe beter.mybe sombody can awnser it instand

Comment: The DontNetBar Combobox made me Head-ache. But, Finally I became achiever. The actual problem was the 'sender' was not responding like textbox. I just created a funtion for searching the combobox itms according to combobox text. if cmbText is same to cmbItem increase progress. iF cmbtext is nothing it decreasing. But it uses three Events. If u suggest better way I will follow you. I am happy with ur help.

Comment: Furst of all if it works it work.you could also check combobox selected idex.if its -1 its emty else there is somthing slected.and check it in the selected index change event of the combobox.